# Need help identifying seeds

Tags: identification, seeds, planting, planting-times

I ordered seeds from a "garder" on aliexpress. I was looking to order Soursop seeds, however the seeds I received were not what I was hoping for. Could somebody help me with figuring out what kind of seeds they actually are? Does anybody know what they could be? I'm stumped. As I don't know what kind they are, I have no clue as to planting and caring for them so they grow properly or if I even need or want them anymore. :( Thanks in advance to all who can assist me.

[image: Random seeds ordered]

Comment: A bit late now, but treat those seeds for disease before planting.

Answer (score 1):

all of the seeds not labeled as rose, look like some sort of muskmelon... no real way to identify them until you plant them and see what grows.